# Using User Profile Fields

Tags: moodle

The Moodle system has a profile for each user that logs on. In that profile you can fill in fields like your name and email address.

Moodle has various activities that can be used to build courses. One of the activities is called a "Lesson". This is a resource that allows you to provide text that guides the student on what to do.

My question is asking whether it is possible to use these fields, for example "First Name" and "Surname", in the text in those lessons. I want to extract them from the user profile of the logged in user, and use them somewhat like a mail merge, i.e insert the value extracted directly in the text. Is this possible?

i.e.

`Hello {{First Name}}. Welcome to lesson 1.`

Comment: Since I got a downvote for being unclear, I have attempted to clarify my question. Sorry for being unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature of the 3rd-party plugin [Generico](https://moodle.org/plugins/filter_generico), but you'll have to read through the [documentation](https://docs.moodle.org/en/filter_generico) in order to understand exactly how to use it.

Comment: Thank you for the headsup @davosmith, I wasn't even aware of this plugin. I will go and read up about it.

Comment: I see that Moodle v3.11 has added a feature called "user profile fields" but I am struggling to understand exactly what it is. I'm hoping that it might be the equivalent of the 3rd party plug-in you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The $USER object contains this, and much more data.  Thus $USER->firstname would give the required data.

Comment: Could you give an example of the syntax you would use to embed something like $USER->firstname into the HTML text in a lesson?

Comment: Hi - I wonder if this is something that can now be done with Moodle v3.11? I would still very much like to understand how to do this please?